# GIT feature branching strategy for a very small dev team

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I'm looking for a bit advice regarding best practice for using version control with a very small dev team. I'm wondering if what I'm doing currently is considered good practice or not.

Basically I have a master branch that is always supposed to be stable with production code. And we have feature branches that represent new features that are being worked on. My team consists of two devs: me who works on a backend API in Django and another guy who writes an angular front end to consume this API.

What we do currently is create a feature branch and I build the API for that feature, while I'm working on this the frontend guy writes the front end for that feature. I almost always finish and move on to the next feature, and most of the time this requires me to make edits to same files from the previous feature branch. So when I finish the second feature branch I almost always have merge conflicts after the first one has been merged into master.

These merge conflicts are usually fairly simple to resolve, but it just feels like we are doing something wrong. I wonder what you think about the way we are doing things and if anyone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays [Long-lived feature branches](https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/techniques/long-lived-branches-with-gitflow) (1)(2) are considered anti-pattern (conflicts as you mention are one of the flaws).

To avoid that I would to suggest to take a look to [Trunk Based Development](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/5-min-overview/):

> A source-control branching model, where developers collaborate on code in a single branch called ‘trunk’ *, resist any pressure to create other long-lived development branches by employing documented techniques

And particularly pay attention to [Short Lived Branches](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/short-lived-feature-branches/) section (i.e: merging to mainline continously).

Since you will merge features that might not be complete to *master*, you will have to use [Feature Flags](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/feature-flags/) and [Branch by Abstraction](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/branch-by-abstraction/) to toggle this features.

(1): https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/enabling-trunk-based-development-deployment-pipelines

(2): https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/short-lived-feature-branches/